# Figuring Out Bindings for 4 level Tree View item in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, treeview

I have a flat file of products that look something like this:

```
 public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>{
 new Product{Name = "OIS Swap", AssetType="Rates",ProductType="Swap",Currency="USD"},
 new Product{Name = "Libor Swap", AssetType ="Rates",ProductType="Swap",Currency="USD"},};
```

I want to populate a TreeView in WPF by categorizing like this:

```
USD
--Rates
----Swap
------OIS Swap
```

First, I have generated a 4 level hierarchy using Linq like this:

```
class HierarchyViewModel{
    public static IEnumerable<CurrencyViewModel> Currency {get;set;}
       public  HierarchyViewModel()
        {
            Currency = Products
                .OrderBy(prod => prod.Currency)
                .GroupBy(prod => prod.Currency)
                .OrderBy(group=> group.Key)
                .Select(group =>
                    new CurrencyViewModel(group.Key, group.Select(prod => prod).ToArray()
                        )
                        ).ToArray();

        }
    }

    class CurrencyViewModel
    {
        public string currency;
        public IEnumerable<AssetTypeViewModel> AssetTypes { get; set; } 

        public CurrencyViewModel(string currency, IEnumerable<Product> CurrencySorted)
        {
            this.currency = currency;
            AssetTypes = CurrencySorted
                         .OrderBy(prod => prod.AssetType)
                         .GroupBy(prod => prod.AssetType)
                         .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
                         .Select(group => new AssetTypeViewModel(group.Key, group.Select(prod => prod).ToArray()
                             )
                             ).ToArray();
        }
    }


    class AssetTypeViewModel
    {
       public string assettype;

       public IEnumerable<ProductTypeViewModel> ProductType { get; set; }

      public  AssetTypeViewModel(string assettype, IEnumerable<Product> AssetSorted)
       {
           this.assettype = assettype;
           ProductType = AssetSorted
               .OrderBy(prod => prod.ProductType)
               .GroupBy(prod => prod.ProductType)
               .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
               .Select(group => new ProductTypeViewModel(group.Key, group.Select(prod => prod).ToArray()
                   )
                   ).ToArray();
       }

    }

    class ProductTypeViewModel
    {
        string producttype;
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products;
        public ProductTypeViewModel(string producttype,IEnumerable<Product> ProductSorted)
        {
            this.producttype = producttype;
            Products = ProductSorted
                .OrderBy(prod => prod.ProductType)
                .Select(prod => prod).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

In my XAML, I do the bindings like So:

```
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type xy:CurrencyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding currency}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding currency}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type xy:AssetTypeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding assettype}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding assettype}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type xy:ProductTypeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding producttype}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding producttype}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xy:Product}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>

    </TreeView>
```

The codebehind for my Usercontrol is

```
public GraphTreeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            MyTree.DataContext = new HierarchyViewModel();
         }
```

But for some reason, the treeview does not populate. I tested the Hierachy generation and it seems to work as intended. I am sure there is some error in my bindings and I would appreciate your help in figuring it out.
Thanks in advance!

**Update** : Using Xavier's answer, I was able to drill down to:
USD
---Rates
----Swap
The last level is still missing.

**Update 2** After a bit of wrangling, and using Snoop to check how its bound, I 'hacked' into the answer. Turns out, The binding **was** (as intended) spitting out a  list of 'Product' classes which had no ToString() method defintion. I overrode those in my class definitions and used an `ItemContainerStyle` as a resource to define the last leg Binding. Here's the full XAML if anyone is interested. Many thanks to Xavier who set me on the right path.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <xy:ProducttoNameConverter x:Key="ProductToNameConverter"/>
        <ItemContainerTemplate x:Key="LastLegConverter">          

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>

        </ItemContainerTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
 <TreeView  x:Name="MyTree"  ItemsSource="{Binding Currency}"> 

            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xy:CurrencyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding AssetTypes }" >

                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCurrency}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xy:AssetTypeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductType}">

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyAssetType}"/>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xy:ProductTypeViewModel}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LastLegConverter}" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProductType}"/>


                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                </TreeView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the `ItemsSource` on the `TreeView` itself to the outermost collection. Also, you need to set the `ItemsSource` property on each of your data templates to the collection of children in the associated viewmodel.

For example:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Currency}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xy:CurrencyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding AssetTypes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding currency}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        ...
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Setting the `ItemsSource` on the `TreeView` gets the process started for populating the control, then the data templates defined for the items in the collection control how each item is presented.

The purpose of a `HiearchicalDataTemplate` is to inform each child view where to find the child items for each item of that type. So, each `TreeViewItem` will use the content of the associated template to construct its view and use the `ItemsSource` property to find a collection of items for which to create its own child views. The process continues until the entire tree is generated.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working on the first three levels but for the last level is where I face a problem. I specify an Itemtemplate inside the last HierarchicalDataTemplate. And then set a DataTemplate with itemsource IEnumerable<Product> Products inside that to show a TextBox with Product.Name. It refuses to drill down. Would you happen to know why that is?

Comment: Well, Its because the Last Hierarchical data template, i.e the ProductTypeViewModel has no children. but it does have an Enumerable list of products which I would like to extract.